# Dynamically add textview on click of button in ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, textview

I have a `scrollview`. I have put a `textfield` and a button over it in same line. I want when user enter a `URL` in `textbox` and click on `button`, `URL` should be added dynamically created `textview` over `textbox` and `button`. (I am using `textview` because it automatically detect the `URL` and present as link).
I have already tried following codes but it is not working:

**1.**

```
- (IBAction)addLinkClicked:(id)sender  {

    NSLog(@"Add Link button clicked");
    UITextView *linkTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    linkTextView.text = @"http://google.com";
    linkTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:linkTextView];
}
```

**2.**

```
- (IBAction)addLinkClicked:(id)sender  {

    NSLog(@"Add Link button clicked");
    UITextView *linkTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    linkTextView.text = @"http://google.com";
    linkTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    [self.scrollView insertSubview:linkTextView atIndex:[self.scrollView.subviews count]];
}
```

Please help me to resolve my issue.

Comment: Set the UITextView Frame

Answer (score 1):

My friend, you need to set the frame for the UITextFiled...

You have two possible ways:

```
UITextView *linkTextView = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)]
```

Or

```
UITextView *linkTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
linkTextView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
```

Cheers!

Comment: this is comment not a answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set the frame for the textview:

```
linkTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 35, 70, 20)]; //put the values you want
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the answers above are same and was right. Just an alternate answer, you can add a `textview` also with the same frame when you creating your `textfield` and `button` and set its `hidden` property to true. Once the `button` is tapped, hide the `textfield` and `button` and show the textview by setting `hidden` to false.